# Get Facebook video id from fb.watch alias

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get the video id from a fb.watch url that you get when you Copy Link on a video?

For example, this url :
https://fb.watch/7zK5NDl3Dw/

has the video id 762932621316078 when you visit the link.

I would like to use the Video Graph Api, but it doesn't work with the alias /7zK5NDl3Dw.  It does work with the id /762932621316078

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out that the URL component might be a BASE64-variant of some sort  encoding of the video id (integer value), as the hypothesis is thoroughly explained concerning YouTube video/channel ids here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/101153/269990. It would actually make total sense for both representations to be mutually convertible as it would directly prevent a massive volume of database storage and queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fb.watch is just a link shortener, you can get a normal video URL by opening the fb.watch link with any HTTP client and checking the redirect URL. No API is needed.

```
$ curl -i https://fb.watch/7zK5NDl3Dw/

HTTP/2 302
location: https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=762932621316078&ref=sharing
x-fb-rlafr: 0
document-policy: force-load-at-top
pragma: no-cache
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 0
x-frame-options: DENY
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; preload; includeSubDomains
content-type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
x-fb-debug: mIg31ie708sE6kGaRk7AVYWyELO5ZWqghkainJunir2RhsLeqCLYSqjDvF8mi6TQ6g2m50TQ/YRTPWW/u90BUg==
content-length: 0
date: Mon, 14 Mar 2022 16:15:51 GMT
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
```

Comment: Unfortunately location always is `https://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser` when I do curl fb.watch - any idea?

Comment: @wepli23 still works for me, try setting another User-Agent header

Comment: Oh yes, another User-Agent did work!